# jquery dialog inside a form works only once

Tags: php, jquery, html

I know this question has been discussed a lot of times.
I have tried all the given answers, without success.

Inside a long form whose id="imprim" and name="imprim", I use a jQueryUI dialog box to give the user a choice between items to print, opened via a button.

It works fine the first time the button is clicked, but on the second time, the overlay shows up, and the page freezes.

Here's my jquery code,  inside `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`...

```
//init dialog
var $print = $('#items_toprint').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            close: function() {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("#imprim");
                $('#items_toprint').dialog('close');
            },
            buttons: {
                VALIDER: function(p) {
                    p.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("#imprim");
                    $(this).dialog('close');

                }}
        });


//button action

        $('#bttn_print').on("click", (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $print.dialog('open');
        }));
    });
```

And HTML (PHP generated) code:

```
    print '<form method="post" id="imprim" name="imprim" action="imprime.php">'; 



    print '<div id="items_toprint" align="center" title = "Choix des graphes" style="display:none" >';
$sql1 = " SELECT p.id as criterid, p.code, p.libelle ";
$sql1.= " FROM " . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . "c_param as p ";
$sql1.= " WHERE p.active = 1";
$sql1.= " AND p.id  IN (SELECT fk_parametre FROM " . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'patient_params WHERE fk_patient = ' . $patient->id . ")";
$sql1.= " order BY p.code";

$result1 = $db->query($sql1);
$num = $db->num_rows($resql);
if ($num >= 1) {
print '<table class="noborder" width="450px" align="center">';
$categ_encours = "";
$der_categ = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {

    $categ_encours = $row[code];
    if ($categ_encours != $der_categ)
        {
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td width="300px" Style="color:#B40431" align= "center">';
        print $categ_encours;
        print '</td>';
        print '<td>';
        print '&nbsp;';
        print '<td>';
        print '</tr>';
        $der_categ = $categ_encours;
        }
    print '<tr >'; 
    print '<td width="300px" class="titre_noir" align= "right">';
    print $row['libelle'];
    print '</td>';
    print '<td  align= "left">';
    print '<input type="checkbox"  name ="graph_toprint[]" value="'.$row['criterid'].'" >';
    print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';
    }
        print '<tr>';
print '<td class="titre"  align="center">'; 
print "Tableau paramètres";
print '</td>';
print '<td align="left">';
print '<input type="checkbox" name="tableau_param[]"  value="t_param" CHECKED = "checked">';
print '</td>';
print '</tr>';
    print '</table>';
}

else {

    print '<p align="center" font-color="red" ><b>';
    print "Vous ne suivez aucun critère pour ce patient !";
    print '</b></p>';


    }

print '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a js function with name PageEvents call this function in document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
PageEvents();
});



function PageEvents(){
     $('body').on("click","#bttn_print", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $print.dialog('open');
            });
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. Despite the "e.preventDefault()", when button is clicked the form is submitted....

Comment: where your button exist in the form?

Comment: @Gerard13007 i edited my answer please check now, you put some extra paranthesis...

Comment: Ok, please check now. and confirm me @Gerard13007

Comment: I fear that this cause other problems...  my javascript page includes a lot of scripts and is not dedicated only to this form.

Comment: more info :In my initial code, if i remove  "$(this).parent().appendTo("#imprim");"  the dialog box can be opened many times without problem...BUT nothing is recorded in the form....